# A transgenre puzzle with rowing

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, language, geography

> Capital city that matches [A-H]+,
>   take out the first four and then add deux cents plus;
>   crossing the Danube, you make your way north;
>   stay on that route till the coastline comes forth.
>
> Apply s/A/H/ and then scramble what you get,
>   take out your oars as well, try not to get wet;
>   remove the last two and then triple the rest,
>   we have a winner, you're clearly the best!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Capital city that matches [A-H]+,`

Although almost every capital city has at least one of those letters, let's use a poetically liberal regexp engine that allows no other letters in the name at all. That gives us the starting point of

> **BAGHDAD**

`take out the first four and then add deux cents plus;`

> Drop the "BAGH", interpret "DAD" as a hexadecimal number, and [add 200](https://www.google.com/search?q=0xDAD+%2B+200), or "C8" in hexadecimal, to get **E75**.

`crossing the Danube, you make your way north;`
`stay on that route till the coastline comes forth.`

> [Route E75](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E75) does indeed cross the Danube, and it meets the Baltic Sea at **GDYNIA**, Poland.

`Apply s/A/H/ and then scramble what you get,`

> Replacing the A with a H, we get GDYNIH, which we scramble into a [**DINGHY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinghy), matching the title and the next line too.

`take out your oars as well, try not to get wet;`
`remove the last two and then triple the rest,`

> **DING DING DING**

`we have a winner, you're clearly the best!`

Comment: Aha! Well done, I'd been too restrictive on the first clue. Mind you I never would have got the second.

Comment: Any Dota 2 gamer/watcher will remember these words directly :P... nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

**Very partial:**

Capital city that matches [A-H]+,

> Only European capital I can think of is Belgrade (or technically BELGRADE), which conveniently is on the Danube (but as Lord Farquaad pointed out actually fails the regex)

take out the first four and then add deux cents plus;

> RADE and CC ? Not sure what to do with this

crossing the Danube, you make your way north;
stay on that route till the coastline comes forth.

> RIGA is mostly north of Belgrade, on the coast

Apply s/A/H/ and then scramble what you get,

> Applied to RIGA, give RIGH

take out your oars as well, try not to get wet;

> Add ROW> RIGHROW .. I've gone horribly wrong

Comment: (You might want to check that your capital city matches that regex)

Comment: Ha! Good point, failed at the first hurdle! Doh!